# compiz refresh rate keeps resetting itself to 50

Tags: nvidia, xorg

compiz refresh rate keeps resetting itself to 50 every time you restart the pc this only happens with nvidia with nouveau driver everything looks good but gets very hot pc reaches 80

Comment: This question is a little hard to understand, since there's no real question here.  What are you trying to ask?

Comment: I have same issue. Whenever I change refresh rate on CCSM, it will be reset into 50 after logout-login!

Comment: I have the same problem with the proprietary Nvidia driver on 13.04. Are you sure nouveau is affected as well?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in compiz. For now the only solution is to set the value on every restart:

Create a shell script, make it executable and put it in the start up application list. The shell script should contain the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/composite/refresh-rate "60"
```

For more information read here: [Changing "Composite > Detect Refresh Rate" is ignored initially](https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1027868)

Comment: I did but it does not work

Comment: It doesn't work for me too

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to "Startup Applications":

Command

```
sh -c "sleep 10 && dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/composite/refresh-rate "60" &"
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?